# How to set multiple JPanel Click Events in a for loop?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, final

```
for(int row=0; row<3; ++row) {
    for(int col=0; col<3; ++col) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.addMouseListener((MouseListener) new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(row) + " " + String.valueOf(col));
            }
        });
        this.add(panel);
    }
}
```

I want something like this but it complains that row is not final variable

```
Local variable row defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
```

I've tried other ways but I can't find how to pass those parameters(row, col) without error messages.

Comment: Do you have two variables named row?

Comment: @JFan No only one in the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    private int row;
    private int col;
    
    public void Panel(){
        for(row=0; row<3; ++row) {
            for(col=0; col<3; ++col) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.addMouseListener((MouseListener) new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        System.out.println(String.valueOf(row) + " " + String.valueOf(col));
                    }
                });
                this.add(panel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Steffi